# getting error installing the composer in existing magento2 project

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

Magento2 Composer install is not working. I'm getting an error when installing the composer in an existing project:

[image: getting error when installing the composer in magento 2 existing project]

Answer (score 0):

You need valid credentials from your Amasty account. It could be that the credentials you're using have expired..

Log into your Amasty account to check, and make sure you've added your amasty keys to auth.json

Comment: i created the account on amasty and given the username and password, but same issue..